# Help sort to list by date

Tags: android, arrays, list, sorting

I have an array list sorted from oldest to newest. I want to change it so that it is sorted from newest to oldest. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the source of your data? Is it database cursor?

Comment: @user617936 if you are getting the data from a database you can just use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to reverse the order of an array?

```
Collections.reverse(yourSortedList);
```

See [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%3C?%3E%29)

Comment: yes tank you,  final ArrayList<HistoryBean> history = m_db.selectAllHistory();
        Collections.reverse(history);
        m_db.closeDatabase();

Answer (score 0):

This is just a java question rather than Android:

```
    ArrayList<String> originalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = originalList.size(); i > 0 ; i--) {
        newList.add(originalList.get(i));
    }
```

I'm sure there are other ways that differ that can be discussed.